# How to add fontawesome icons in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm adding fontawesome icons in my page, but these icons are not working, although I added a cdn link in my file:

```
<div id="footer">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">coyright@2021 company name</div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <ul id="social-icons" class="float-md-right">
         <li><a href="" class="fa fa-facebook-square"></a></li>
      <li><a href="" class="fa fa-twitter-square"></a></li>
      <li><a href="" class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of Fontawesome and how did you load it?

Answer (score 1):

In the `<head>` of your html, reference the location to your font-awesome. min. css. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

Answer (score 1):

stackoverflow is sandboxed and won't load the fonts.  Try your code in jsfiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/a9jvfebw/

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div id="footer">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">coyright@2021 company name</div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <ul id="social-icons" class="float-md-right">
         <li><a href="" class="fa fa-facebook-square"></a></li>
      <li><a href="" class="fa fa-twitter-square"></a></li>
      <li><a href="" class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the Font Awesome icons, add the following line inside the head section of your HTML page.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="footer">
         <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">coyright@2021 company name</div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <ul id="social-icons" class="float-md-right">
                     <li><a href="" class="fa fa-facebook-square"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="" class="fa fa-twitter-square"></a></li>
                     <li><a href="" class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Try this code. And check it once again, where you have added  tag.

Comment: They said they had done that already

Comment: But in his code snippet, the <link> tag is not mentioned. For working font awsome in Html, cdn link should be there in the head tag. Otherwise it will not work if the link tag is not properly closed.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the font family:

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the Font Awesome library, you will need to request it from eighter downloading it to your local machine or via using cdn. In both ways you will need to connect it to your HTML document by specifying the link to the external file in your **<head>** tag. It should look like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div id="footer">
     <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">coyright@2021 company name</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <ul id="social-icons" class="float-md-right">
                 <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook-square"></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter-square"></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Note**: The href attribute of a tag may not be empty. It is required to have a value of eighter a link, `javascript:void(0)` or a # sign in order to be a valid HTML, as well as the `<html>` tag has to have a mandatory lang attribute.